# How to calculate values in a 3*3 matrix using raster calculator?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster-calculator

How to manipulate a raster values in a 3 X 3 matrix.. using raster calculator or any other method e.g. to find out how many cells are there in a 3 X 3 matrix having cell values less than the center cell.. and sum them up...

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that there is a simple way to do this in ArcGIS.

You should first create 8 files with the values of the pixels around your center pixel. This can be done by shifting the raster or using the focal statistics tool with a custom filter e.g.

```
3 3
0 0 0
1 0 0
0 0 0
```

for the left pixel.

Then you can use Map algebra on those pixels to get the value that you expect (with "pixel11" being the raster including the center pixels)

```
Con("pixel00" > "pixel11", "pixel00", 0) + Con("pixel01" > "pixel11", "pixel01", 0) + ...
```

alternatively, you can convert your [raster to a numpy array](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//000v0000012z000000) and do your processing in numpy.